# Как сделать переход по минутам с видео на vimeo?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, vimeo

Внимания на скриншот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть видео что будет грузиться с Vimeo. И снизу есть пункты + тайм лайн. Можно ли как то сделать что бы при клике на них, видео будет на той же минуты что задали справа. Видео интегрируется через iframe или можно как то иначе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы с конкретного времени видео грузилось вам просто в ссылку надо добавить это время. 
К примеру:

```
https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345678?autoplay=1#t=1m2s
```

или так

```
https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345678#t=1m2s
```